# Adding javascript inside blogger Post

Tags: javascript, blogs, blogger

How can i add the following javascript inside a post

```
<script type="text/javascript">ch_client = "dddsul";ch_width = 550;ch_height = 250;ch_type = "mpu";ch_sid = "ChiDefault";ch_color_site_link = "0000CC";ch_color_title = "0000CC";ch_color_border = "FFFFFF";ch_color_text = "000000";
ch_color_bg = "FFFFFF";</script>
<script src="http://scripts.chitika.net/eminimalls/amm.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: Which server side language are you using ?

Comment: This is a very vague question.
Do you mean programmatically, then which programming language? Does it have to be executed or shown as text, ...

Comment: I want to post a blog using javascript

Comment: have you tried something already? are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When editing a post in Blogger, just click on HTML button as shown below:

[image]

This will display content of your post in HTML, so just copy / paste your javascript code there.